# PyQt4 - how to share variable between different callables?

Tags: python, pyqt4

So I want my GUI window to collect data from the user and open up the specified text files after the user has confirmed that the selections had been made. I created a global dictionary to store the information the user put in, but I have no clue how to send this dictionary to the next function call. I kept on getting the error "global name 'fileName' is not defined". Help please!!

Sample Code:

```
class guiFindFiles(QtGui.QWidget):  
fileName = {}

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    #Create window
    self.setFixedSize(400,180)
    self.setWindowTitle("Choose the files to use")
    self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
...

    #Connect all the signals and slots
    self.connect(self.qFileButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.loadFile)
    self.connect(self.lhButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.loadFile)
    self.connect(self.oldQButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.loadFile)
    self.connect(self.oldQCB, QtCore.SIGNAL("stateChanged(int)"), self.status)
    self.connect(self.run, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"),self.close)
    self.connect(self.run, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"),self.goForth)

def loadFile(self):                     
    selFile = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()

    if self.sender() == self.qFileButton:
        fileName["currentQ"]=selFile
        self.qFileTF.setText(selFile)
    elif self.sender() == self.lhButton:
        self.lhFileTF.setText(selFile)
        fileName["currentLH"]=selFile
    else:
        self.oldQTF.setText(selFile)    
        fileName["oldQ"]=selFile

def goForth(self):
    print fileName[0]
    self.close()
```

Error Msg:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qDis.py", line 80, in loadFile
    fileName["currentQ"]=selFile
NameError: global name 'fileName' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `loadFile` method, you're looking for `fileName`, *ie* a loval variable which is not defined in your function nor in the rest of your module, hence the `NameError`.

Most likely, you meant to use `self.fileName`, *ie* the class attribute you have defined earlier.

The same remark and suggestion apply to your other method `goForth`.

As a sidenote: do you really need `fileName` to be a class attribute? Couldn't it be just an instance attribute you would define in your `__init__` method ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, adding self. fixed the issue.

Comment: I was testing if without "self.", I could still get the other functions to recognize the variable, it doesn't have to be a class attribute. Although it will make things easier because I have a second GUI that builds tabs procedurally using the info I get from this dictionary.

Comment: But you'll have an instance of `guiFindFile` defined somewhere, right? So you could still access the `fileName` attribute of this instance.